# Не правильно работает метод Substring

Tags: c#

Не могу понять в чем суть есть простая 2 строчки кода но компилятор мудрит :

```
   string text = " TITLE OF THE DOCUMEN </ title ></ head >< body >< h1 > hello </ h1 >";
   text = text.Substring(22, 31);
```

После компиляции выдает "`</ title ></ head >< body >< h1`".
В чем проблема?

Comment: Что конкретно Вас не устраивает? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Извиняюсь не так прочитал документацию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лезем в msdn, посмотреть [что же делает метод substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx).
Видим, что вторым параметром в него уходит длина подстроки, а не позиция конца.

Answer (score 3):

Никакой проблемы нет, то, что Вы написали, то Вам и выводится. В строке `"</ title ></ head >< body >< h1"` ровно 31 символ, а начинается это подстрока как раз на 22 символе.